# How to proxy shared internet

Tags: macos, proxy, internet-sharing

Using Wireshark, I need to sniff some traffic on my mobile device. I've set up my Mac to share my Ethernet connection to computers using Wi-Fi, and then I set my mobile device to connect to that wifi.

Now, I want to proxy all the of the requests from the mobile device and watch the traffic from there. I cannot set a proxy on the device. There's no interface to do it unless I root it, which I don't really want to do (yeah, tell me about it). So, I need to set the proxy on the shared internet.

The thing is, I set the proxy on my wi-fi network, but I'm not seeing the traffic go through the proxy. If I set the proxy on my ethernet, I don't see the mobile device's traffic go through the proxy; all I see is my host computer's traffic.

So how do I set up a proxy on my shared internet connection?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're doing, and trying to do. First, if all you need to do is sniff traffic, why are you bothering with a proxy? Wireshark can simply capture the packets as they go by. Second, if you do need a proxy, please explain what you're doing in more detail (especially, what proxy software are you using, and how do you have it set up).

Comment: You can set up a web proxy on OSX in System Preferences > Network > choose your network > Advanced > Proxies

Comment: That setting tells software running on your Mac (e.g. Safari) to use the configured proxy (when connecting to the Internet via Wi-Fi), but does nothing at all to traffic being routed through your computer. Again, please clarify what your goal is here. What do you actually need to do with the traffic from your mobile device?

Comment: I'm trying to troubleshoot my apps that are running on Android. It's running a bunch of different ad networks' SDKs, so I want to find out what they're doing, if anything. But the Androids I have won't allow a proxy unless you root the phone, which might invalidate the test.

Comment: Do you need to spy on SSL (HTTPS), or just plain HTTP? Do you need to interfere actively with the connection, or just watch what's being sent & received?

Comment: @JeremyDetrempe i don't get why others don't quite understand your question. i *think* i do, you have some proxy settings configured in OSX and want those same settings to apply to a device connected to your Mac via Internet Sharing. **i wish** i had an answer.

Comment: I've been using Charles Proxy for this for years.